# No module named '_tkinter' error message when using pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I'm trying to use pyinstaller to create a basic Mac app using tkinter. The file itself, saved under the name example.py, is just

```
from tkinter import Tk,Label
window = Tk()
window.title("My Window")
lbl = Label(window, text="Hello World")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

Very simple. Now

```
pyinstaller example.py --onefile --windowed
```

produces an app bundle, but I'm unable to run the program from the terminal using

```
./dist/example.app/Contents/MacOS/example
```

due to the the error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

The spec file looks like this, where I've edited to include tkinter as a hidden import.

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['pyinstaller_basic'],
     pathex=['/Users/fishbacp/Desktop/Python_May_2021'],
     binaries=[],
     datas=[],
     hiddenimports=['tkinter'],
     hookspath=[],
     runtime_hooks=[],
     excludes=[],
     win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
     win_private_assemblies=False,
     cipher=block_cipher,
     noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
      cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      [],
      name='example',
      debug=False,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      upx_exclude=[],
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=False )
app = BUNDLE(exe,
      name='example.app',
      icon=None,
      bundle_identifier=None)
```

Now I create the app using

```
pyinstaller example.spec example.py --onefile --windowed
```

Still, I get the same error message when trying to run the app from the terminal.

I'm using Python 3.9 on a Mac running Big Sur.

Comment: `$ pip install tk` doesn't work for you? If you are using pycharm, and it is red underlined, you can left click on it and import.

Comment: tk is installed. I've been using it all the time--it's just when I try to combine it with pyinstaller. In fact, I've used it successfully with py2app.

Comment: for me that works `pyinstaller  --onefile -w your.py`

Comment: Still have the problem. Could it be a problem with Big Sur perhaps?

Comment: ```pyinstaller -F --hidden-import=tkinter --hidden-import=tkinter.filedialog yourfilename.py``` is this working for you?

Comment: Didn't work either. It does function fine on Windows though. I think it's a Big Sur issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have just faced the same issue and solved it.

> If you use virtual enviroment you should go in your enviroment for example mine: D:\GitHub\SnA-KPIS-JSON-Editor\20_Implementation\venv

> If you use system/allFor Python go inside your Python, path could look like this : C:\Users\YourLogin\Programs\PythonX.X

> > Inside in the Python folder copy folder named **Library** and just copy it inside your folder with .exe file. File you built with pyinstaller.

Feel free to remove any other folders inside **Library** but **bin**, that must stay. It's key to solve the issue.

If you have images which are used in tkinter you have to copy and paste them inside your build folder as well.

It's simple and easily done. Hope this will help some others which are will face the same issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).